# OnItemSelectedListener kept changing to adapter view

Tags: android, spinner, onclicklistener

I want to create a spinner that retrieve data from database but `OnItemSelectedListener` won't work. It keeps suggesting to adapterview.OnclickListener but the coding need OnClickListenerOnly.

```
package com.example.win7.fyp;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.Settings;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;

import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class student_register extends Activity implements  OnItemSelectedListener {
Toolbar toolbar;

private ProgressDialog progressDialog;

JsonParser jParser = new JsonParser();
private static String URL_TO_PASS = "http://arcafyp.xyz/chat/register_student.php";

SharedPreferences pref;

EditText username5, password5 ,advisorName5;
TextView advReg;

String username1;

String AndroidId;

private ArrayList<Category> categoriesList;
ProgressDialog pDialog;
private Spinner spinnerFood;


// Url to get all categories
private String URL_CATEGORIES = "http://ekinidris.site40.net/chat/advisorName.php";



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_student_register);
    pref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("MyPref", 0);//  0 - for private mode



  username5 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.register_matrixno);
  password5 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.register_ic);
    advisorName5 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.advName);


    spinnerFood.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
     spinnerFood = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinFood);


    categoriesList = new ArrayList<Category>();

    // Add new category click event


    new GetCategories().execute();
}





private class GetCategories extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(student_register.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Fetching advisor name..");
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();

    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        ServiceHandler jsonParser = new ServiceHandler();
        String json = jsonParser.makeServiceCall(URL_CATEGORIES, ServiceHandler.GET);

        Log.e("Response: ", "> " + json);

        if (json != null) {
            try {
                JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(json);
                if (jsonObj != null) {
                    JSONArray categories = jsonObj
                            .getJSONArray("categories");

                    for (int i = 0; i < categories.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject catObj = (JSONObject) categories.get(i);
                        Category cat = new Category(catObj.getInt("phone_id"),
                                catObj.getString("name"));
                        categoriesList.add(cat);
                    }
                }

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        } else {
            Log.e("JSON Data", "Didn't receive any data from server!");
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        if (pDialog.isShowing())
            pDialog.dismiss();
        //populateSpinner();
    }

}

/**
 * Adding spinner data
 * */
private void populateSpinner() {
    List<String> lables = new ArrayList<String>();

    advisorName5.setText("");

    for (int i = 0; i < categoriesList.size(); i++) {
        lables.add(categoriesList.get(i).getName());
    }

    // Creating adapter for spinner
    ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, lables);

    // Drop down layout style - list view with radio button
    spinnerAdapter
            .setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

    // attaching data adapter to spinner
    spinnerFood.setAdapter(spinnerAdapter);
}









@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
     //Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_student_register, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.register_send) {
        new registerUser().execute();
        String newCategory =  advisorName5.getText().toString();

        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}





class registerUser extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        Intent i = getIntent();
        String studentPhone_id = i.getStringExtra("phone_id").toString();
        String studentUsername = username5.getText().toString();
        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(student_register.this);
        progressDialog.setMessage("Processing Data" + studentPhone_id + studentUsername);
        progressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        progressDialog.setCancelable(true);
        progressDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
        String studentUsername = username5.getText().toString(); // matrix no
        String studentPassword = password5.getText().toString();  //cgpa
        String studentAdvName = advisorName5.getText().toString();  //advisor name


        Intent i = getIntent();
        String studentPhone_id = i.getStringExtra("phone_id").toString();



        List<NameValuePair> param = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        param.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username",studentUsername));
        param.add(new BasicNameValuePair("phone_id",studentPhone_id));
        param.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", studentPassword));
        param.add(new BasicNameValuePair("advisorName", studentAdvName));

        JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest("http://ekinidris.site40.net/chat/register_student.php","POST",param);



        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();

        Log.d("data", json.toString());

        try {
            int result = json.getInt("success");
            if(result == 1) {

                editor.putString("phone_id",studentPhone_id);
                editor.commit();

                Intent intent = new Intent(student_register.this, MainActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("phone_id", studentPhone_id);
                intent.putExtra("username",studentUsername);
                intent.putExtra("advisorName",studentAdvName);

                startActivity(intent);

                finish();
                progressDialog.dismiss();
            }else{
               To be edited.....
                 put some action refreshing the page
            }

        }catch (JSONException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        super.onPostExecute(s);
        progressDialog.dismiss();
        finish();
    }
}
```

}

logcat

```
11-06 16:43:02.289  22071-22071/? E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity     ComponentInfo{com.example.win7.fyp/com.example.win7.fyp.student_register}: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.win7.fyp.student_register cannot be cast to android.view.View$OnClickListener
        at  android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1968)
        at  android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1993)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:127)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1159)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4507)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:980)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:747)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.win7.fyp.student_register cannot be cast to android.view.View$OnClickListener
        at com.example.win7.fyp.student_register.onCreate(student_register.java:78)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1052)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1932)
```

Comment: setOnItemClickListener will not works with spinner.

Comment: setOnItemSelectedListener

Comment: Can you show us your imports? And where is the implemented methods from `OnItemSelectedListener` this interface?

Comment: what imports ? sorry kind a new in this

Comment: i edit my code already

Comment: Is that your whole code? because I don't see initialization of `spinnerFood`. like `spinnerFood = findViewById(R.id....)`

Comment: oh sorry , yes it does . i solve the setonclicklistener problem , but the data wont display . but in logcat it retrieve from server

Answer (score 0):

follow this code-

```
spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                int arg2, long arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            String msupplier=supplier.getSelectedItem().toString();

            Log.e("Selected item : ",msupplier);
}

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });
```

Comment: same the OnItemSelectedListener keeps suggesting to adapterView

Comment: post your log cat. what is it suggesting

Comment: i tried this and i changed this public class student_register extends ActionBarActivity and its works . but the spinner wont display the data , but in logcat its already retrive the data

Comment: if its not showing data in spinner then its completely related to adapter. there should be some problem with your adaptr

Comment: im not sure which one was the adapter . i follow the code from androidhive (spinner from mysqldatabase)

Comment: if my spinner doesnt display all data , but only display one data ? why is that ? i think my array is correct though .

Comment: set debuger on your populate spinner because you are binding values to spinner in this.. and check whether all values are coming in lables list and from there going in spinner

Answer (score 0):

I used same answered by sud but with little modification which worked

```
spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                   int pos, long id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
       // String msupplier=supplier.getSelectedItem().toString(); instead used below
        Log.e("Selected item : ", (String) parent.getItemAtPosition(pos));
     }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
});
```